# django second request in queue until first request complete

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django, tried to understand how multiple request can handle at the same time.

i have app with two html and two different function and i put sleep 40 sec for one function ( one.html) and second function no sleep just render the html (second.html).

opened one.html in one browser and second.html in another browser ( shows nothing ), because one.html will wait for 40 sec to complete.

Django: 3.2.3
Runserver: python manage.py runserver ip:port

Tried uwsgi but multi request not working: uwsgi --http  --module app.wsgi --processess 4 --master --threads 2

Appreciated for any ideas/solutions provided.

Comment: This is expected for the runserver development server since it's single-threaded. For the uwsgi/gunicorn it should work in parallel if ran by separate processes. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: What is the goal?

Comment: Parallel processing not working when I use uwsgi and runsever

Comment: Goal to achieve parallel processes for requests